# Optional boolean parameter comes in as an Object in TypeScript constructor

Tags: typescript, serenity

As the title says. I have the following constructor in a TypeScript class. This is within Serenity framework.

```
constructor(private isAllRequest?: boolean) {
    super();
    // initialise grids
    this.requestAbsenceInteractionGrid = new RequestAbsenceInteractionGrid(this.byId("RequestAbsenceInteractionGrid"));
    this.requestAbsenceDocumentGrid = new RequestAbsenceDocumentGrid(this.byId("RequestAbsenceDocumentGrid"));
    this.requestLogGrid = new RequestLogGrid(this.byId("RequestLogGrid"));

    if (isAllRequest) {
        this.fromAllRequest = isAllRequest;
    }
}
```

Instead of a `boolean`, I get the following:

[image]

This is obviously troublesome because doing an `if` on an empty object always returns `true`. I need that param to be a `boolean`, and **it should be**, but I don't know why it isn't.

If I do the following:

```
if (typeof isAllRequest === 'boolean' && isAllRequest) {
    this.fromAllRequest = isAllRequest;
}
```

Then I get the expected behaviour, but I'm confused why that's necessary. I'm telling TypeScript that the param is of type `boolean`.

**How is that constructor called?**

The constructor which sits on a dialog class is opened via a link like so: [image: link to open serenity dialog]

Could it be that [Serenity](https://github.com/serenity-is/Serenity) by default passes in an object?

Comment: How are you calling this constructor? Looks like you are passing an object to it.

Comment: Use console.trace({isAllRequired}) to see what what passes to constructor

Comment: I'm not following. How exactly do you know it's an object at runtime.